# equals() method in rectangle and box classes

Tags: java

I have a class hierarchy which is shown below...

```
public class Rectangle2
{
    // instance variables 
    private int length;
    private int width;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
     */
    public Rectangle2(int l, int w)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }
    // return the height
    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Rectangle - " + length + " X " + width;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Box2 extends Rectangle2
{
    // instance variables 
    private int height;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class box
     */
    public Box2(int l, int w, int h)
    {
        // call superclass
        super(l, w);
        // initialise instance variables
        height = h;
    }
    // return the height
    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Box - " + getLength() + " X " + getWidth() + " X " + height;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Cube extends Box2 {
            public Cube(int length)
             {
              super(length, length, length);
             } 
            public String toString()
    {
        return "Cube - " + getLength() + " X " + getWidth() + " X " + getHeight();
    }
}
```

I want to add a equals() method to all the class so that if the output of one class equals the other classes output it will print "Box and Cube have the same dimension." I am really confused. All I know is that I have to use a `if-else` statement but after that I just can't think of what to do.

This is what my question says to do:
3. Also add an equals() method to the classes, so that you can determine when two Rectangles, Boxes, or cubes are equal based on the values of their dimensions. Cube should inherit the equals method of the Box class rather than override it. 
This is how the output should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgti1.png

Comment: Why are you overriding the equals method to print out stuff?

Comment: Because my teacher told me I have to put this method in. It looks useless but I need to do this for my assessment.

Comment: please read Java Object equals  method and why and how to use it.

Comment: @user2059140: you are likely misunderstanding your assignment requirements. Please don't paraphrase what you think the requirements are, post them verbatim here in your question, and perhaps we can explain them to you so that you do understand them.

Comment: do you mean a Cube is equals to a Box2 whose length,width,and height is equal and equals to the Cube's length?

Comment: I did but I am not getting how I would do a if-else statement with the output of one class and another class.

Comment: Ok i just edited my post with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private final int length;
    private final int width;

    public Rectangle(int length, int width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle - " + length + " X " + width;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (length * 159) + (width * 523);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Rectangle)) {
            return false;
        }
        Rectangle that = (Rectangle) obj;
        return this.hashCode() == that.hashCode();
    }

}
```

You need to override hashCode when you override equals because the [contract of hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) states that the hashCode must be the same if the objects are equal. The implementation of hashCode should try to avoid producing the same hashCode for different objects but this is not a hard requirement. Therefore an approach like shown here is good enough. The hashCode is mainly used to distribute objects nicely in datastructures that use a bucketing system like HashMap, so for the performance of such datastructures it is useful if the hashCodes have a good spread.

```
    public class Box extends Rectangle {

    private final int height;

    public Box(int length, int width, int height) {
        super(length, width);
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Box - " + getLength() + " X " + getWidth() + " X " + height;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode() + (height * 343);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Box)) {
            return false;
        }
        Box that = (Box) obj;
        return this.hashCode() == that.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Box can just call super.hashCode() and add a factor for the extra parameter 'height'. Note that with this approach a box with height zero will have the same hashCode as a Rectangle with the same length and width. This is not a requirement but it may be useful in certain conditions.

```
public class Cube extends Box {

    public Cube(int length) {
        super(length, length, length);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Cube - " + getLength() + " X " + getWidth() + " X "
                + getHeight();
    }
}
```

Cube can just hike along on the work done in Rectangle and Box. The reason this all works out so nicely is that the fields in all these classes are immutable (e.g. there are no setters). I emphasized this by making them all final so the compiler really makes sure they cannot be changed. If you had setters you could create a cube and then set the width to a different value. This would screw up this design. For more information see the article ['A Square Is Not A Rectangle'](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea, but you can define `equals` in `Box2` as follows:

```
public class Box2 extends Rectangle2 {
  //...

  boolean equals(Object o) {
   //a quick check if we are comparing with ourselves
   if (this==o) return true; 

   //no object is equals to null
   if (o==null) return false;

   //compare only if o is an instance of Box
   if (o instanceof Box2) {
     (Box2) that = (Box2) o;
     if (this.getWidth()!=that.getWidth()) return false;
     if (this.getLength()!=that.getLength()) return false;
     if (this.getHeight()!=that.getHeight()) return false;
     return true;
   }

   //instances of other classes cannot be equal to this instance
   return false;
  }

}
```

Since `Cube` extends `equals`, any `Box` with the same dimensions will be equal to another box with the same dimensions. A `Cube` is a `Box`.

**Why is it a bad idea?** Suppose that we have a class `BoxWithColor` that extends `Box` and adds a variable for representing the box color

```
public class BoxWithColor extends Box {
  public String color;
  public BoxWithColor(String color, int l, int w, int h) {
    super(l,w,h);
    this.color=color;
  }      
}
```

now `new BoxWithColor("red",1,2,3).equals(new Box(1,2,3))`, which is wrong.

Usually, equals should be reserved for **instances of the same class**.

Comment: `if (that==null) return false;` line is wrong. `that` doesn't exist yet! Should be `o==null`